# How to use flutter url_launcher function from separate file?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that is very similar to the url_launcher example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'url_functions.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: ListView(children: [
      new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: urlfunc.launchURL,
          child: new Text('Show Map'),
        ),
      ),
    ], padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)));
  }
}
```

The code was working when urlfunc.launchURL was in the same file as my widget and called _launchURL.

This is the code for url_funtions.dart:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

// https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher
class urlfunc {
  launchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://flutter.io';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

I would like launchURL to be in a separate file so that other widgets can use it too. However, when I moved the code to url_functions.dart I got this error message:

> error: Instance member 'launchURL' can't be accessed using static
>   access.

How can I use launchURL from a separate file?

Comment: Try to rename the function `_launchURL` to `LaunchURL`. I feel like because of the underscore (_) the function can't be called anywhere from the file it is in. I've met this issue before and removing the _ solved my problem.

Comment: Yup that change is already made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can Use Word **Static** in front of your function:

```
class urlfunc {
  static launchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://flutter.io';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

}

**OR**

You can initiate the Class urlfunc then call the function:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  urlfunc myFunc = urlfunc();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: Text("MiniCon")),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(children: [
        new Center(
          child: new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: myFunc.launchURL(),
            child: new Text('Show Map'),
          ),
        ),
      ], padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0))),
    );
  }
}

class urlfunc {
  launchURL() async {
    const url = 'https://flutter.io';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you can instantiate the class.

Comment: Yes that is the option too.

Comment: Pls feel free to add that to your answer :)

Comment: Done... @Dennis